# MySQL remote server connection failed w Navicat

Tags: mysql-error-2003

I am trying to connect to a MySQL remote server. I was able to connect prior to moving my internet service to Suddenlink.

I am now getting the error:
2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'www.server.com' (10038)

I have added my new IP address to Remote MySQL.

Any suggestions as to what may be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your effort

Comment: Any ideas or suggestions? I struggle with joins and this tool really helps.

Comment: I still need help with this. Anybody got any ideas? Please!

Comment: please refer to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55060341/mysql-server-8-0-remote-database/55084155#55084155